# How to hide a canvas or complicated element using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

If we use

```
this.props.flag && <Foo ... />
```

and `<Foo />` is a canvas or some complicated HTML element with a lot of offsprings, isn't it true that each time, the canvas or the whole subtree can be re-rendered / redrawn, depending on how the browser does it or have any optimization?

If that's the case, isn't one of the best way to do

```
<Foo 
  show={ this.props.flag }

  ... 
/>
```

and inside of `<Foo />`:

```
render = () => {
  return (
    <canvas
      style={ this.props.show ? {} : { visibility: "hidden" } }
      ...
    />
);
```

};

I thought about using `display: "none"` instead of `visibility`, but isn't `display` have a higher possibility of having the canvas or element re-render / redraw?  The `visibility` occupies real estate so it may be a problem, but if it is imposed on other elements or canvas (such as using `position: absolute`), for example, if it is 3 canvases stacking up on one another, then it would be just fine?

Comment: What is your desired outcome? You want that element to be rendered but not visable? Or do you want it to not be rendered at all?

Comment: if it is rendered once, that's fine. I just don't want it to be rendered again and again